# What is the difference between HTTP and HTTPS headers?

Tags: http, https, http-headers

Can you please explain the different between http header and https header. I need very brief explanation. What will we do using http/https header?.

Thanks

Comment: HTTPS is an abbreviation for HTTP over TLS/SSL. So what do you mean by HTTPS header? The header of TLS/SSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http, https, ftp, etc are there to tell the server which protocol is being used, so it knows where to direct the request.

http is unencrypted, usually on port 80. https is encrypted with ssl, usually on port 443.

Comment: No. http:, https: ftp:, etc. are there to tell the *browser* or other client what protocol is being used. All the server needs is the port number.

Answer (score 9):

After the SSL negotiation, normal HTTP headers will travel inside the encrypted stream, so there is really no difference between the two.